# jQuery .val() test returning blank

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am attempting to return the attribute "value" for each index of an html, according the the [jQuery DOM Manipulation Documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_dom_get.asp) I should be able to use .val() in order to return this however when I print to the console, I get a blank value. using .html() I can return the section of html which clearly shows that the value is there. So, my question is:

How do I get the value attribute as a real value vs blank.

please see my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3kWNh/617/)

**Javascript**

```
$("table#Table tr").each(function( i ) {
  $("td", this).each(function( j ) {
    var test = $(this).val()
    console.log("".concat("row: ", i, ", col: ", j, ", value: ", test));
  });
});
```

Comment: A `td` does not have a `value`.

Comment: That was no reason to downvote him, he is here to learn and the question was proper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

value is not valid property of td elements and td do not have it. You need to find the input element in td and then get the value.something like this:

```
$("td input", this).each(function( j ) {
  var test = $(this).val()
  console.log("".concat("row: ", i, ", col: ", j, ", value: ", test));
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LfkrhLjL/)**

Comment: Great, I didn't realize that, still learning about elements and their properties.

Comment: @TylerCowan: glad it helps :)

Answer (score 2):

`<td>` elements don't have values.  But the inputs within them do.  It looks like you just need to use `"td input"` as the selector instead of just `"td"`:

```
$("td input", this).each(function( j ) {
  //...
});
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3kWNh/618/)

Comment: What does `this` do here ?

Comment: @mrid: It adds context to the selector.  So the selector is looking for `"td input"` matches but *only* in the context of `this`.  In this case `this` would be the `tr` elements being iterated in the previous line.